# simple url to url via RewriteRule in htaccess not working 

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect  a single URL to another single URL, no parameters or anything

*domain.com/snow* **to**

*superdomain.com/longer/url/snow*

i am trying with, in .htaccess the following:

```
RewriteRule ^snow http://superdomain.com/longer/snow [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^snow$ http://superdomain.com/longer/snow [R=301,L]
```

But none of them are working, any idea what am I missing?

Note: the url's are only examples but they have same structure than what i need

Comment: yes i have other redirections working already, weird, no?

Comment: Post the surrounding lines from .htaccess. Maybe an earlier `RewriteCond` affecting this due to a missed `[L]` somewhere?

Comment: just found out! /snow/ flolder had its own .htacess :)

Comment: You can answer your own question then and accept it

Answer (score 1):

just found out! /snow/ **flolder had its own .htacess** :)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need parameters or anything, [RedirectPermanent](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) is a simpler option:

```
RedirectPermanent /snow http://superdomain.com/longer/snow
```